# goBack() is making my app force close when hitting the back button

Tags: android, webview, navigation

I am trying to make the back button of an android device be a way of navigating backwards in a WebView. However, when I click the back button, it force closes instead.

This is my .java file (edited out package name):

```
package ----;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ---- extends Activity {
WebView mainWebView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadUrl("https://app.tent.is/global");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mainWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post error logs for better understanding of your problem , you can use onBackPress() method instadeof onKeyDown... I can solve if proper error provided to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here

`WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);`

change with

`mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);`

The thing is the object `WebView mainWebView;` you declared before `onCreate`, and it is never being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the code

```
  package ----;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class ---- extends Activity {
    WebView mainWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://app.tent.is/global");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mainWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
```